# Where are unsaved files in notepad++ stored?

Tags: wine, backup, notepad-plus-plus

I had installed notepad++ using Softwares in my Ubuntu 18.04, which installed notepad++ using snap. Now, for some reason, my notepad++ is not opening. But I want to get all the unsaved text files I had opened in my previous session. Where can I find these unsaved files?

Most of the questions on web deal with Windows, but not for ubuntu. They usually say that the files are saved in a folder named backup. I searched in the home directory, snap directory. I couldn't find any folder named backup.

Comment: I haven't used Notepad++ on Linux, but it appears to actually be the Windows version running in Wine, so you might need to look inside a Wine prefix. (Normally they would be in `~/.wine`, but I'm not sure where they get put for Snaps.)

Comment: Thanks. Found it in `/home/nagabhushan/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/users/nagabhushan/Application Data/Notepad++/backup/`

Comment: Thank you very much, this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be somewhere below `~/.local` or maybe `~/.cache`.

I'd try a `find` for files in the home directory that have changed during the last 3 days (or whenever you used it last):

```
find ~ -mtime -3
```

Or maybe start first with `~/.local` to avoid dozens of web browser cache files scrolling by:

```
find ~/.local -mtime -3
```

Comment: Thanks. It was not there in `.local`. I tried `find ~ -mtime -10 | grep notepad` and found that the backup folder is situated in `/home/nagabhushan/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/users/nagabhushan/Application Data/Notepad++/backup/` All my files were there.

Answer (score -1):

On the following Ubuntu:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Backup files are located in:

```
/home/$USER/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/users/$USER/AppData/Roaming/Notepad++/backup/
```

`$USER` is used to get the current user name in your system.

In my case,

```
$ ls /home/$USER/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/users/$USER/AppData/Roaming/Notepad++/backup/
'new 1@2023-07-24_131201'  'new 1@2023-07-25_225938'  'new 1@2023-07-27_000008'  'new 1@2023-07-30_215759'  'new 1@2023-08-01_145110'
'new 1@2023-07-24_154340'  'new 1@2023-07-26_220545'  'new 1@2023-07-28_122836'  'new 1@2023-08-01_120730'  'new 1@2023-08-01_145923'
```

On the other hand, you can **view and edit your backup path** for Notepad++:
*Open Notepad++ and click Settings > Preferences > Backup*

In order to avoid previous session snapshot case, I modified it as:
*Backup on save > Verbose backup > Custom Backup Directory > C:\users\USERNAME\Desktop\BackupNotepad*

Instead of "C:\users\USERNAME\Desktop\BackupNotepad", place directory whatever you would like. Verbose backup basically adds a timestamp when saving the file.

Comment: In the question is: "my notepad++ is not opening", So the suggestion to view/edit the backup path in Notepad++ is useless for this question.

Comment: plus acc.to comments TS found it at "home/nagabhushan/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/users/nagabhushan/Application Data/Notepad++/backup"